# python requests.get with invalid URL

Tags: python, http, url, python-requests

I'm coding a short code to check if the url is valid or not.
However, when I'm checking for invalid URL it does not respond with
any error-ish status code. It just don't run the code.

Can I get some help with this code below:

```
import requests
import string

# Welcome to IsItDown.py!
# Please write a URL or URLs you want to check. (separated by a comma)
#
# input()
#
# <check for valid URL>
#
# Do you want to start over? (y/n)
# if y:
# elif n: print(Okay. Bye!)
# else: That's not a valid answer

def url_check(urls):
  for url in urls:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
      print(f"{url} is up!")
    else:
      raise Exception(f"{url} is down!")


print("Welcome to IsItDown.py!")

urls = ['google.com .', '   na1v2e12312r.com ']

for index, item in enumerate(urls):
  item = item.strip(string.punctuation).strip()
  if "http" not in item:
    item = "http://" + item
  urls[index] = item

print(urls) 

try:
  url_check(urls)

except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

Comment: `It just don't run the code.` Really? What output do you get? Is an exception thrown that you're catching? Maybe you could be catching the exception and handling it?

Comment: @Random Davis HTTPConnectionPool(host='na1v2e12312r.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7efc88f33b50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Comment: So why can't you catch `NewConnectionError` and handle that case?

Comment: I just want to know the status code for an invalid URL to print out "URL is down". But the code doesn't get further because of the error.

Comment: You only get a status code if you were able to connect to the url.  But you weren't able to do that, so there _is_ no status code.

Comment: Is there a way just to print out "URL is down!" in else statement in that case? I can't find a way if invalid URL is inserted to request.get() method

Comment: Use a try/except as @RandomDavis suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the error you get when you try to access an invalid URL:

```
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7efc88f33b50>: 
    Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')
```

That means that in order to catch the error and indicate that the URL is invalid, you'd have to use `try` and `except` like you're currently doing, except instead you'd catch that specific error:

```
try:
    resp = requests.get(url)
except NewConnectionError:
    print(f'Invalid URL: "{url}"')
    # at this point, you can continue the loop to the next URL if you want
```